# How to add in app purchase in one feature of an application of android?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, partial

I have prepared an application which has several features. To one feature of them, I want to add in app purchase option. Can anyone inform me the simplest way to implement this? As far I know it can't be tested using emulator. Then How can I test it after adding this option?

Comment: What do you mean simplest way? Are you experiencing problems with some code you tried that you want us to point you in the right direction? I believe the Android docs has all of your questions answered.

Comment: I also believe the android docs has all explanations. But I am little bit impatient to read thoroughly the docs. So, basically I need to know the simple sequential processes which I have to follow to implement and in app purchase for a feature of my application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last, I have implemented in app purchase in my application with the help of bellow's website which contains brief but clear explanation of in app purchase with a simple example. Possibly this site will be helpful for the novice android programmers to learn how to implement in app purchase.

[techotopia-In app purchase](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Integrating_Google_Play_In-app_Billing_into_an_Android_Application_%E2%80%93_A_Tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

you can make a test account in your developer console under setting, upload the apk with in-app billing permissions but don't publish it.
Add in-app products in developer console.
Login with the same test account you have added in developer console as primary account to your android device.
then install the signed apk into your device
and you are ready for testing

you can also refer to android.developer for more details 
http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html